# What is the maximum number of region in which the plane is divided?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, euclidean-geometry

Fifteen lines are drawn in a plane such that four of them are parallel.What is the maximum number of region in which the plane is divided?......Tried to solve but did not get any idea

Comment: Try the problem for smaller values of fifteen (like 3, 4, 5) and see if you notice a pattern.

Comment: If you get stuck, take a look at this: http://franklin.dyer.me/entries/2017-2-19.html